# Installing Ubuntu 13.10 alongside, 13.04. Potential boot loader issues

Tags: 13.04, 13.10, partitioning, windows-8, bootloader

Below is an image of my hard drive partitions as they exist currently.

[image]

`/dev/sda4` is Windows 8

`/dev/sda9` is Ubuntu 13.04

`/dev/sda5` is where I plan to install 13.10 as I am currently not using it for anything.

My goal is to have both versions of Ubuntu bootable for a time while I test the 13.10 installation. Once I feel confidant in it I will install something else to sda9.

Also on the 13.10 installation I plan to install /home to its own partition.

I have two questions:

1. Does anyone for see any issues I will likely run into with the bootloader?
2. What is a good standard ratio of disk space to allocate to the home partition and the root partition?

**EDIT:** All the standard stuff of disabling fast boot, secure boot etc. is already taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to decide which version (13.04 or 13.10) controls the boot loader.  You will need to use expert mode when you install.

   1. You could point 13.10 to install the boot loader at /dev/sda5 (it's partition) and then you will see grub twice when you boot 13.10.  You can then set it to point to /dev/sda when you are ready to remove 13.04.  This is probably the easiest.
   2. Alternatively, You can tell 13.10 to skip installing a boot loader and then configure 13.04 to include 13.10.  Then install the boot loader under 13.10 when you remove 13.04.
2. Your mileage will very.

   1. I'm at 59% with a 24GB "/" partition.
   2. Since you are dual booting windows and linux, I would probably keep /home to a modest 4G and dump the rest of your data under an NTFS partition so it is visible by both.  If you are especially daring, you could make /home an NTFS partition and give everything available to it.